# Why RecatJS do not update value when it changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I`m learning React and I do not understand - why in first render React generate correctly value **playerSymbol**, but when It changes it is not re-render even when **gameBoard** changes. Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const initialGameBoard = [
 [null, null, null],
 [null, null, null],
 [null, null, null],
];

export default function GameBoard() {
  const [gameBoard, setGameBoard] = useState(initialGameBoard);

  function handleSelectedSqare(rowIndex, colIndex) {
    console.log("aaaa");
    setGameBoard((prevGameBoard) => {
      const updatedBoard = [
        ...prevGameBoard.map((innerArray) => [...innerArray]),
      ];
      console.log(updatedBoard);
      updatedBoard[rowIndex][colIndex] = "X";
      return updatedBoard;
    });
  }

  return (
    <ol id="game-board">
      {initialGameBoard.map((row, rowIndex) => (
        <li key={rowIndex}>
          <ol>
            {row.map((playerSymbol, colIndex) => (
              <li key={colIndex}>
                <button onClick={() => handleSelectedSqare(rowIndex, colIndex)}>
                  {playerSymbol}
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ol>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: The problem is that you are rendering initialGameBoard instead of gameBoard.  In your setState prevGameBoard.map already returns a new array so it's not needed to be wrapped in `[... ]`

Answer (score 2):

```
  {initialGameBoard.map((row, rowIndex) => (
```

was called instead call **gameBoard**

Answer (score -3):

You are not changing the state of gameBoard. You need to pass in the new board to setGameBoard().

```
setGameBoard(updatedGameBoard)
```